# Javascript: Simple function, var not getting set

Tags: javascript

What am I doing wrong here? I even tried it with `case`  instead of `if` and it does not work

```
function updateResultPage(the_resp,r) {
    var to_alert="s";

    if(the_resp=="11"){
        to_alert="Thank you!!";
    } 
    else if(the_resp=="22"){
        to_alert="Error:.";
    }
    else if(the_resp=="33"){
        to_alert="ERROR 234dfR,.";
    }

    alert("c "+to_alert+the_resp);
}
```

I get an alert that displays `C s22`

Why is it skipping past all the if() statements?

EDIT:
Ok, I added this code to see the exact value of resp: `alert("d "+to_alert+" *"+the_resp+"*");`
and the second * is coming on the next line, so it looks like i have a trimming problem...

Comment: Because you have no `else` only option, your `else if`'s are not being matched and the result is the variable is not set.

Comment: I get that, but if you see in the alert I have `the_resp` and that IS displaying 22, so why is it not matching?

Comment: What are you talking about, that should work. Also why does your function take two arguments?

Comment: Seems to work for me. (chrome 12 and FF 5)

Comment: Well, I should have said that the `to_alert` variable would not have changed from the original value.

Comment: It Works on my computer!

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, after trimming it worked :) Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this

`alert("c "+to_alert+the_resp);`

or add an `else`

```
else{
    alert("c "+to_alert+the_resp);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
the_resp = the_resp.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,"");  // will trim it.
```

at the beginning of your function.

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth checking to make sure you are passing in an actual string or string object (as opposed to say an int).  May also be worth making sure there isn't any non-printing whitespace in your input by trimming appropriately..